# Approximate cost of iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much does it cost to develop an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209170/how-much-does-it-cost-to-develop-an-iphone-application)

What would be the approximate cost to have an iPhone application developed similar to the USA Today and Sky News applications?

Thanks!

Comment: [This previous SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209170/how-much-does-it-cost-to-develop-an-iphone-application) may help guide you to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on various Factors .
I am a 16 year old iOS app developer and develop apps for free for my school and my dads company etc ...

But if you dont know anything about developing it could cost you +$100,000 to get a custom made app

Comment: This seems like it should be a comment rather than an answer.  Please consider expanding your answer further.