# How long/how much did it cost to develop iPhone SDK & App Store

Tags: iphone, sdk, app-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much does it cost to develop an iphone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209170/how-much-does-it-cost-to-develop-an-iphone-application)

Hope somebody can help. I have been googling trying to get an indication of how long it took apple to develop the AppStore & the iPhone SDK?

My Co. have had an idea to try and do a similar thing internally for our own apps and  massively underestimating the amount of work that will be required.

If anybody has any idea how long Apple spent developing the SDK & AppStore, links to any pages even better, I would be very grateful for the info so that I can use that for discussion about the plans.

Cheers

Comment: It's not even remotely a duplicate of that. That's the problem when people are in a hurry and only read the title

Comment: @SeniorShizzle I agree that it's not an exact duplicate. However it is not answerable by anyone other than Apple, so, best case, it would get reopened and closed again but for a different reason...

Comment: Thank you so very much the 5 people who closed my question without properly reading the details, this question bears no resemblance to the proposed duplicate and only SeniorShizzle seemed to take the time to look at it properly and comment appropriately.

Comment: @Stephen Darlington thank you for looking at the question.  I understand what you're saying I was hoping that somebody in the community may have come across something I hadn't, I understand that only Apple could give a definitive answer

Comment: Can't we just reopen the question? Get Zaf, Michael Petrotta, Alex Reynolds, Ole Begemann, and Ngu Soon Hui back here now

Comment: The guy isn't looking for second-specifics, he just wants some facts he can use to convince boss he's being a dumba$$. I wish I had 3000 rep, or at least Nathan had 250.

Comment: While not a duplicate of the suggested question, this is still not a programming-related question and is only answerable by someone from Apple (good luck on getting someone to post internal figures here).

Comment: Not specifically looking for exact figures any ballpark e.g. at least 100 devs for 6+ years for the SDK.  That would be enough

Comment: @SeniorShizzle: ok, I'm back, and I'd close this question again for the same reason I did the first time: it's off-topic.  Please remember that the people who vote to close a question don't all have to use the same reason; majority rules in that case (with some caveats in case of ties).

Comment: Hey! Nice to see you again Mike! Thanks for opening back up the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well apple has hundreds of trained engineers working for them, even still at launch, Steve Jobs said the iPhone took around 6 years to create. Along this time frame they were creating the iPhone SDK which they used to create all the apps built in to the phone. Since then they have been constantly updating the SDK several times a year, expanding a lot. The App Store, my guess is that they used the robust iTunes base they already had for distribution, and then all the rest (legal and technical) things should have taken no time at all.

I'm not sure what your company wants to do but it seems without Apple's resources you'd be better off not.

Comment: I totally agree but they have in their heads that its an easy thing to do and I'm looking for some facts to show that it isn't easy and beyond our resources.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain a little more what exactly your company does, and what they want to do.